# MySQL - String separated by commas to variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called 'Order' and each product inside the column is separated by commas. Is it possible to pull each string from the single cell to its prospected variables?

Example:
Column name: Orders
Values inside a single cell: H001, H002, H003

```
Orders
H001, H002, H003
```

Expected result

```
H1      H2      H3
H001    H002    H003
```

Below is the snipping of the table,

https://snipboard.io/06tkAl.jpg

Comment: can you brief the scenerio behind this logic.May be there will another way to achieve this

Comment: the reason behind this is that each product has a price and I'm planning to add a column call total. I can then use the price to calculate the total. This table is called the packaging and I have another table that has the products individually with it's own price.

Comment: Do one work.Create a seperate table name it "Products_packages".For every package and product create a seperate row in this table.Suppose you will create two foreign keys.One wil lbe package_id and other will be product_id in this new table and then add a join of this table to Products table .This way you can get the price of every Product

Comment: Please use below query `select 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(orders, ',', 1) as H1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(orders, ',', 2), 
    ',', -1) as H2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(orders, ',', -1) as H3 from table_name;`  Demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f16ff96d5f61758425fbfbb1a930fab8

Comment: If `H001, H002, H003` are order numbers (invoice etc.), that means it will grow to a maximum `H999`.. So are you planning to have 900+ columns? (e.g. H1, H2, H3 ... H997, H998, H999)

Comment: tcadidot0 - It's only there, but shouldn't reach 20. Maybe max 10.
Jim - I'll test that. Thanks

Comment: You should change your db design and leave that query alone. It would be so much easier.